# Is the difference between AddQuartz and AddQuartzHostedService that the latter adds a hosted service?

Tags: c#, .net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, ihostedservice

I'm just learning Quartz.NET (and C# in general in fact) and I'm struggling to get my head around the differences between the `AddQuartz` and `AddQuartzHostedService` methods. From what I've seen [here](https://mbarkt3sto.hashnode.dev/scheduling-background-jobs-in-aspnet-core-with-quartznet), [here](https://damienbod.com/2021/11/08/asp-net-core-scheduling-with-quartz-net-and-signalr-monitoring/) and [here](https://tutorials.eu/asp-net-scheduler/), it seems that `AddQuartz` adds and configures the Quartz scheduler, and `AddQuartzHostedService` explicitly adds this Quartz service (which I assume is the configured scheduler) as a hosted service... Have I got this right?

And in what context would I ever use `AddQuartz` if I don't intend to add it as a hosted service? Please help me clear up any misconceptions I might have. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`AddQuartz` configures the scheduling system by adding jobs and when they need to be called.

`AddQuartzHostedService` on the other hand sets up the scheduling system to run in the background as a hosted service, letting it run its jobs and (optionally) wait for any scheduled jobs before allowing the application to exit.

You always use both of them together.

Comment: Thanks @Blindy. I think I see the difference. But if you always use them together, why would they be separate methods?

Comment: Dependency Injection in general isn't known for being terse. In fact, it is quite well known for requiring hundreds of lines of code to do what would otherwise be just a couple.

Comment: The upside of DI is that you can replace either of the two components with your own (for example, for testing, or for a different setup than the default is made for) without having to also change the other component. You probably never will, but the option is there.